# typo3 Default root template shows content, from first page, on every page

Tags: templates, typo3

**Current setup**

[image]

The Startseite page (also seen at https://www.dentalsplace.de/Startseite.html) is the homepage.

I added another testx page and added phonenumber as seen in image:

[image]

Anything i add in testx is useless. It still shows phonenumber from homepage. If i change phone on homepage it is changed on both home and testx.

I want to have different phone for each page. Is there a way to solve this?

---

constants.ts:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/general-constants.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/question/ts/constants.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/contactform/ts/constants.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/newsletter/ts/constants.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/appointment/ts/constants.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/ts/root-constants.ts">
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------


#styles.content.imgtext.maxW = 408
#styles.content.imgtext.maxWInText = 220
styles.content.imgtext.maxW = 1200
styles.content.imgtext.maxWInText = 900

sourceopt.formatHtml = 1
current.title = Dentalsplace - Zahnärztliche Praxis XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

setup.ts:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/question/ts/setup.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/contactform/ts/setup.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/newsletter/ts/setup.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/appointment/ts/setup.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/ts/root-setup.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/question/ts/conversion.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/contactform/ts/conversion.ts">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/sub_templates/formhandler/appointment/ts/conversion.ts">
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

plugin.tx_scriptmerger.javascript.parseBody = 1
#plugin.tx_scriptmerger.css.mergedFilePosition = </body>

[globalVar = TSFE:id=7]
page.headerData.10.field = keintitel
page.headerData.10.noTrimWrap >
page.headerData.10.wrap = <title>{$current.title}</title>
[global]


##Cookie Consent
page.headerData.2021 = TEXT
page.headerData.2021.value (
     <!-- Begin Cookie Consent plugin by Silktide - http://silktide.com/cookieconsent -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.cookieconsent_options = {"message":"Wir möchten Ihnen den bestmöglichen Service bieten. Dazu speichern wir Informationen über Ihren Besuch in sogenannten Cookies. Durch die Nutzung dieser Webseite erklären Sie sich mit der Verwendung von Cookies einverstanden. Detaillierte Informationen über den Einsatz von Cookies auf dieser Webseite erhalten Sie durch Klick auf.","dismiss":"OK","learnMore":"Mehr Informationen","link":"https://www.dentalsplace.de/datenschutz.html","theme":"dark-bottom"};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/1.0.10/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
<!-- End Cookie Consent plugin -->
<style>
.cc_banner-wrapper .cc_container .cc_btn, .cc_container .cc_btn:visited{
background-color:#7D337C;
color: #fff;
z-index:999;

}
.cc_banner-wrapper .cc_container a.cc_more_info{
color:#7D337C;
}
.cc_banner-wrapper .cc_container a.cc_more_info:hover{
color:#fff;
}

</style>

)
```

root-setup.ts added in pastebin due to character limit
https://pastebin.com/Ds3Marqe

Comment: Can you post your TypoScript which renders the FE output? This might be the important thing.

Comment: Don't know how to edit the question.
Here is the template Constants and Setup
https://pastebin.com/KxXQCXHg

Comment: Remove identifying data! Please insert more information about your system (Version numbers and used extensions). your link to edit should be a light gray `edit` below your question (and not the misleading tag I removed)

Comment: the relevant typoscript is not in your data as it is in included files, the most important part probably is in `fileadmin/templates/ts/root-setup.ts`. on the other side I also could imagine a wrong fluid-template, where you might insert a column of the start page.

Comment: @Bernd Wilke πφ Understood.
A friend told it might be something related to content sliding where content is inherited to other pages.

Comment: it probably is no sliding as sliding would only occur if the column in the current page is empty. therefore I think it is a hardcoded misreference.

Comment: Added the root-setup.ts to the question. i still have no idea why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it.
You do

```
page.10.variables {
    homevar < styles.content.get
    homevar.select.pidInList = 7 <<< This means you only get content from page with UID 7

    phone < .homevar <<< Here you copy that part into phone
    phone.select.where = colPos = 125
```

You copy the part with `pidInList = 7` to every other configuration.
Either use another part to copy from or remove the restriction from `phone`: `phone.select.pidInList >`